# Looking for hardware firewall having very well maintained and updated web category filters?

Tags: firewall

Right now I am using a small Sophos XG firewall to do SSL inspection and blocking of web categories. Unfortunately, in my opinion, web categories are not very well maintained and updated by sophos. Is there another product that keeps its categories more up-to-date?

EDIT: Performance and bandwidth of the hardware are not important, lowest performance is good enough (right now it's the smallest Sophos XG85). Budget should definitely be under 1000 USD.

Comment: As hardware firewall setups tend to be targeted towards enterprise environments, most tend to be pricier than ordinary consumer hardware. If you (or your company) has a budget in place, it may be useful to list it.

Comment: I added budget to my question.

Comment: I would recommend trying the Network Stack Exchange.
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/